# Compound queries in Firestore - different fields in "order by" and "where"

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Will this work in Firebase Firestore?

```
var result = await firestoreInstance
  .collection('messages')
  .where('place', whereIn: ["value1","value2","value3","value4","value5","value6","value7","value8","value9"])
  .orderBy('dateAdded')  
  .startAfterDocument(lastDocument)  
  .limit(documentLimit)  
  .getDocuments();
```

I mean, I want to filter data based on IN condition on one field ('place'), and then paginate it based on another field ('dateAdded').

Will it use a composite index on fields 'place' and 'dateAdded'?
I Firestore allows it, will it work in Flutter SDK?

Comment: Why not just try it yourself?

Comment: When posting to Stack Overflow, it's expected that you actually run your code, then if it doesn't work the way you expect, add your debugging details to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work just fine - I already do similar actions in my code.  One thing I found by trying - paging *back* with an "EndBeforeDocument" call seems to need to *reverse* the orderBy, so it will need to setup multiple compound indexes.  A link to a page to create those indexes *for* you will be returned in the "err" from the .get() call (so set up your callbacks appropriately to catch this).

So Doug is generally right, btw, bad etiquette to ask questions without trying (and/or searching StackOverflow) - you just got lucky because I just wrote my own paging interface for a library for my application.  While I intend to release the interface as an NPM package shortly, it probably won't help you - I'm using the Web API (javascript) under React.